# IIS permissions to open sockets inside unmanaged DLL

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, sockets, azure, iis

I'm developing a .NET MVC Application to query a PLC for inputs and outputs status using Snap7 library.

For development reasons I connect to my PLC (behind a router) using an SSH tunnel bound to a localhost port, so it becomes reachable at 127.0.0.1:102 address. In this scenario, everything works fine and I manage to read data from the device.

When I deploy my application to the production server a subtle problems begins: I'm no longer able to connect PLC. Error code from Snap7 library is cryptic and the only difference in code is the IP address (192.168.1.100:102 instead of localhost:102) so I suspect a permission problem is involved.

I'm searching for two solutions to my problems: one for the normal deployment, where I have full access to IIS Server and one for Azure deployment. I'm searching for something to put inside Web.config but I'm not still able to find suitable configurations or workarounds.

Comment: How do you connect to the PLC from Azure? Site-to-site VPN? Some other way? Are you hosting in App Service, Cloud Services or VM?

Comment: The problem arises also when testing from Visual Studio IIS and connecting to PLC in the same subnet. There are no problems only when PLC appears as 127.0.0.1 (SSH C2S tunneling bound to localhost interface on standard 102 TCP port). My ideal deployment is running my MVC.NET in App Service and connecting to PLC by exposing it directly outside with port forwarding